# SQL Server stored procedure to compare dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to select all the dates from a table and want to find if any date from the table is less than a specific date or not.

When I do

```
select DateEntered from Table1 where ID = 4
```

Result:

```
2015-05-12 06:21:43.600
2018-07-12 06:21:43.600
```

Now I want to return '-1' if any date is less than '2015-06-11 06:21:43.600', else '1'.

So, here I should get -1.

How can I write that stored procedure?

Comment: Have you looked the case expression in sql server? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx (Hint: you will need to use MIN here in conjunction with a case expression)

Comment: You can use `MIN()` for final comparison.

Comment: You don't even need a CASE statement since it sounds like you just need to return a scalar value and not a result set.   You can just use IF...ELSE.

Answer (score 0):

```
select case 
    when DateEntered  < '2015-06-11 06:21:43.600' then '-1'
    else '1'
       end
from Table1 where ID = 4
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to write a stored procedure it would look similar to this:

```
USE mydb
GO

CREATE Procedure dbo.MyProcedure @CurrentDate Date
AS
BEGIN
SET @CurrentDate = GETDATE()

SELECT
 CASE 
   WHEN DateEntered < @CurrentDate THEN -1
   WHEN DateEntered >= @CurrentDate THEN 1
 END AS myvalue
FROM Table1 
WHERE ID = 4

END

GO
```

Comment: I don't think the OP is exactly clear on this point. Until clarification, this is a valid answer.

Comment: IMHO he was very clear: "Now I want to return '-1' if **any** date is less "

Comment: Not sure it is really valid...there are a few errors in here. First is the semicolon, missing keyword AS, END with no BEGIN.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prcName]
(
    @machineId INT

)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT  

        Case when CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), M.EndDate, 112)<CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) then 'InActive' else 'Your Value 1' End as 'Your Value 2' 
FROM [dbo].[MachineUsageCost] M WITH(NOLOCK)

WHERE   (@machineUsageCostId IS NULL OR @machineUsageCostId = MachineUsageCostId) AND MachineId=@machineId  
        and M.IsActive=1
 END
```